# Paypal PHP REST API for payflow

Tags: php, rest, paypal

We would like to use Paypal for credit card authorization exactly as we do for Paypal transactions, only skip right to approval for users who do not want paypal.

The REST API for paypal has the setPaymentMethod always set to "paypal" in every example I can find, and I don't find a list of possible values. May this constant be set to something like "payflow"?

The hope is that the REST API would work to allow a credit card customer get payflow dialogs rather than paypal login/guest login. The idea is to try and use our existing REST code to process credit card payflow transactions and retain the "create order" then "capture" processes we have for paypal transactions. I can't tell if the REST API is capable of this.

Answer (score 0):

Payflow does not work with the REST API in any way. Payflow is very old, and uses a much older NVP API.

If possible, use a more modern solution such as [Braintree Direct](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-direct) or [Advanced Credit and Debit Cards](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/) rather than the old Payflow gateway.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is exactly what I needed to know to put away the false hope. We are looking at Braintree as the solution, but I was trying to reuse if possible. I apologize that I don't have sufficient reputation to vote your answer as the solution.

Comment: Well Advanced Credit and Debit Cards does use the REST API to create and capture orders